# How to send and receive Complex object in web api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api

IDE: Visual Studio 2012

I have controller as follows:

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{

  public IHttpActionResult AddMyControllerInfo([FromBody]Dictionary<string, string> dictCustomer)  
  {
     //Some logic...
      return Ok("Success");  
  }
}
```

And it is being called from client project:

Calling code is as follows:

```
internal static void SendInfoToMyController(Dictionary<string, string> dictCustomer)
    {

        string jsDict = Utilities.SerializeToJson<Dictionary<string, string>>(dictCustomer);
        string js = Utilities.MakeRequest_Post("/api/AddMyControllerInfo", jsDict);

    }
```

and here is Make request function:

```
internal static string MakeRequest_Post(string sURL, string formData)
    {
        try
        {

            sURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerApiPath"] + sURL;


            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                var result = client.UploadString(sURL, "POST", "=" + formData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return "";
    }
```

Above code is working fine when I receive the [FromBody] parameter data in the form of string (json format) datatype, and deserialize it to dictionary form.

but in above scenario I am receiving dictionary object as null.

Can you tell me how to receive the complex object at web api, for above scenario.

Comment: it is in json dictionary format.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong content type in your requests. In your `MakeRequest_Post` method, change the content type header as follows:

```
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
```

I believe you also need to remove the leading `=` from the POST body like this:

```
var result = client.UploadString(sURL, "POST", formData);
```